# How can I print the gradated color stdout results to a terminal?

Tags: fish, iterm2

- OS - macOS High Sierra v10.13.1(17B48)
- Terminal - iTerm2 (Build 3.1.5)
- Shell - fish, version 2.6.0

My environments is like above, 
and I wonder how to print a command results with **gradation colors**,
like asciinema demo?
(sorry for lack of a link, attaching a followed image rather than it)

screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vdf2.png)

Comment: https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks!!

Comment: @SushiHangover I have another question about stackoverflow. I think un-answered questions, like this question, affect me a bad reputation.. Would you mind let me know why you've just an comment, NOT an answer?

Comment: Directly linking to off-site resources is not really an "answer" and I had idea if that was what you were really looking for. Unanswered questions do not affect reputation.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for explanation!